# The $2$-norm of an outer product

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

> **(The $2$-norm of an outer product)** Let $A$ be the rank-one outer product $uv^*$, where $u\in\mathbb C^m$ and $v\in \mathbb C^n$. For any $x\in\mathbb C^n$ I can use the C-S inequality to bound $\|Ax\|_2$ by 
>   $$
> \|Ax\|_2=\|uv^*x\|_2\leq\|u\|_2\|v\|_2\|x\|_2.
> $$ 
>   Then
>   $
> \|A\|_2\leq\|u\|_2\|v\|_2$. In fact the inequality is an equality (think about the case $x=v/\|v\|_2$) so $\|A\|_2=\|u\|_2\|v\|_2$.

I not sure how to get this to be an equality. Do I start at the right of the expression and somehow get it eqaul to the left??

Comment: The paranthetical note "consider the case $x=v/\| v \|$) tells you how to find a case where $\leq$ becomes $=$.

Comment: Hi Brian, I know im just having difficulty showing it

Comment: What is the dot product of $v$ with itself?

Comment: I don't get this either.  it shows that it _can_ be an equality, but does not show that it is an equality in general.  So, why does it say "In fact the inequality is an equality"?

Comment: To answer my own question above, since an induced norm is taking the supremum (or maximum) of $||Ax||$ over x, with $||x||=1$, then actually this becomes an equality when it gets maximized. @Eamonn this is also true for the Frobenius norm.

Answer (score 3):

"Solve a simpler problem".

- Do you know the *definition* of $\|A\|_2$?
- What can the inequality 
  $\|Ax\|_2\leq \|u\|_2\|v\|_2\|x\|_2
  $ 
  tell you when $x=v/\|v\|$?

Comment: Note that this is also true for the Frobenius norm @Jack

Answer (score 2):

A bit late but anyway, if $A=uv^*$ then $\|Ax\|= |v^*x|\|u\|$ then apply Cauchy-Schwarz in $\mathbb{R}^n$ for $|v^*x|$.

Answer (score 2):

None of the answers above proof the required equality. The aim is to show:
$$\|A\|_2=\|uv^*\|_2=\|u\|_2\|v\|_2.$$
Using the definition of norm-2 of a matrix,
$$\|A\|_2=(\rho(vu^*uv^*))^{1/2}=(u^*u)^{1/2}(\rho(vv^*))^{1/2}=(u^*u)^{1/2}(v^*v)^{1/2}=\|u\|_2\|v\|_2$$
Note that $vv^*$ is a rank one matrix with largest eigenvalue $v^*v$.